# Extension libraries are required to use the PG_MODULE_MAGIC macro

Tags: c, postgresql

I wrote a C extension for my postgreSQL database a few years back (I think it was version 8.0 back then - I am using **Version1 calling conventions**).

I tried to load the extension in a PG 8.4 database using:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foobar(float8[],float8[],float8[],float8[],int4)  RETURNS int4
AS '$libdir/pg_myextlib.so' LANGUAGE 'c';
```

and I got the error message:

> ERROR:  incompatible library
>   "/usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/lib/pg_myextlib.so": missing magic block
>   HINT:  Extension libraries are required to use the PG_MODULE_MAGIC
>   macro.

I did a quick search for this and found some old ng topics about this. They all seem to offer a solution similar to the one [here](http://www.dbforums.com/postgresql/1626234-c-language-external-functions.html).

However, since those threads are old (+ there is no voting on answers), I thought it best to ask in here to see what the correct way of fixing this is.

Aside: Because the underlying library is written in C, I have included C in the tags. Feel free to remove it if you thing 'C' is not a relevant tag for this question.

Comment: Did you try any of the solutions you found?

Comment: Or even better - have you checked the fine manual?

Answer (score 5):

Binary modules are not compatible between mayor versions. PG_MODULE_MAGIC macro ensures it. You have to add this macro to your code and recompile it. And maybe little bit more. Only SPI API is stable - other internal functionality are not - and some small changes are probable.